# Is it secure to transfer certificates from Service 1 to Service 2 over HTTPS?

Tags: tls, certificates

I need to transfer SSL certificates (including their private keys) between two services over HTTPS.

For example, service 1 makes a PUT REST call to service 2 over HTTPS.
Request Payload = The certificate including the private key.

Is that secure? Is there a more secure way to transfer certificates?

Comment: It depends! How is are your requests authenticated? Are you logging anything? It is idempotent? So really, it's less about the fact that you want to send private keys than it is about keeping "any" sensitive information safe and controlling access.

Comment: Does each end validate the other end certificates before doing any kind of HTTPS traffic? HTTPS transport with just confidentiality and no authentication is not very secure. But the problem is the same with any kind of transport, if you do it over ssh do you validate server identity?

Comment: @Marc, Thanks! 
(1) Yes, requests are authenticated via a token. So, only service 1 can make requests to service 2.
(2) No logging of any confidential info.

I am trying to understand if there is any chance of man-in-the-middle attacks or similar issues that I need to address.

Comment: @Patrick,
Thanks. Could you please help explain why/what each party needs to validate about the other party certificate?
Let's say, if service 1 knows that the endpoint of Service 2 is https:// www.service-2.com/UploadCert, and it is using HTTPS transport.
What kind of certificate validation should service 1 (the client) need to do in this case?

Comment: Each end should validate that the other end has a valid (not expired, etc...) certificate from a CA that it trusts. Otherwise: the client may securely (as in noone can sniff) send something to another party (because of a DNS hijack for example or evil proxy, immediate MITM) than the one it thinks about, and in the same way the server may receive data from a totally other party than the one supposed. See this document for some background/pitfalls about not checking endpoints (speaks outside of HTTPS but same problems in it): https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, Thanks much! Makes perfect sense.
So, two more questions please. (1) What is the recommended list of checks to run against a certificate?        (2) The only case the payload can be compromised would be if the attacker compromises either Service 1 or Service 2 SSL certificates. Correct?

Comment: 1) the "SSL" library you use should do all the checks for you... if (see article) its API is not fooling you and you specifically instruct it to fully validate the received certificate (you will have to also define which CAs to trust. All? Commercial ones? Yours only? etc.).  2) imagine client does not check server certificate, and someone manage to change IP of server in DNS (or give the client false data), the proxy could terminate the SSL traffic of the client succesfully and read everything in it but just forward stuff to server so that things look like to work...

Answer (score 1):

Let's restrict the question to network traffic only, so we treat the machines themselves as safe. Additionally we treat the TLS version used as safe (be sure to use the latest, as there were some bugs in previous versions).

The security of HTTPS consists of two parts:

**Authenticity:** If both clients already have some sort of certificate known to the other side or one signed by a CA both sides trust (or a securely implemented token mechanism, like in your example), they can assume, that the client they are connecting to, is in fact the one it claims to be.
This is assured by digital signatures, which we treat as secure at the moment (assuming proper hash and cryptographic algorithms are used, like SHA256 and RSA-2048 or more).

**Encryption:** The security of encryption depends on whether both sides can trust the keys being used. Assuming that neither side leaked a private key, it's safe to assume that nobody except those two clients can participate in the initial key exchange. The digital signatures mentioned above guarantee that the asymmetric keys belong to the other side respectively, while the asymmetric cryptography guarantees that only the owner of the private key can read messages.

If these conditions are satified, both sides can securely agree on a shared secret for this HTTPS session, without anybody in the middle being able to compute the same secret, even if he/she reads all packages being sent.

Edit: Using the method you added to your question, this transfer should be safe (be aware of the conditions above). Be sure that BOTH sides provide a way of authenticating themselves respectively. If the Service A connects to Service B (which is server-side in this example), A checks the certificate of B. They are able to establish a secure connection, but B can't be sure that A is who it pretends to be.

This is where your (hopefully secure) token system should be used. You may also use some other way of authentication but be sure to **use one**, as this could be a serious problem. An attacker being able to import his own certificate into Service B... I say no more ;)

Comment: +1 Theoretically HTTPS should be fine though SCP would be a preferable method ... no idea why you are doing this through a HTTP PUT